# telegram getwebhookinfo returns "SSL error {SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}"

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I want to set self signed certificate for my telegram bot webhook. I used this openssl command to create public key as discussed in [Marvin's Marvellous Guide to All Things Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#a-self-signed-certificate):

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out \
YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=example.com"
```

Then I use **curl** or **postman** to set webhook and send certificate. Both of them just give me **`Webhook was set`** but bot doesn't respond. After that I use [getwebhookinfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#getwebhookinfo) to check the problem.

It returns:

```
"last_error_message": "SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:
tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
```

I googled it but I can't find the solution.
Below you can see some extra info.

[image: Postman set webook]

```
curl -F "url=https://mydomain.ir/responser.php" -F "certificate=@YOURPUBLIC.pem" https://api.telegram.org/bot.../setWebhook
```

My public key is in same folder as cmd runs.

My domain also doesn't have a valid ssl certificate so chrome just show up a warning. ***Your connection is not private***

And I am sure about background code that works, because it was tested before.

Thanks for further help.

Comment: ***`CN=example.com`*** is probably wrong. Hostnames always go in the *SAN*. If its present in the *CN*, then it must be present in the *SAN* too (you have to list it twice in this case). For more rules and reasons, see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Comment: @jww thank you. I don't know anything about SAN. I did everything in Marvin Marvellous guid. What did i forget to do? Please be specific. I am newbie in certificafe and openssl. Thanks again.